# JavaScript "this" context in .replace callback

Tags: javascript, callback, this

Consider the following very simplified example:

```
var some_module = {
    func_a: function() {
        return 'a';
    },
    func_b: function(character) {
        if (character == 'b') {
            console.log(this); //refers to window
            return this.func_a;
        } else {
            return 'X';
        }
    },
    func_c: function() {
        console.log(this); //refers to some_module
        return "abcdefgh".replace(/[abc]/g, this.func_b);
    }
};
some_module.func_c();
```

This fails because in func_b, "this" refers to window because of the call context (as far as i know). I am aware of workarounds, that usually work when nesting functions, however how can I get it to work in this case where the function is used as a callback in .replace()?

Comment: You ought to take a deep breath and step back and make sure you really understand what `this` means and where it comes from. There are plenty of good tutorials, including answers right here on SO, such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work. This question has been asked in one form or another probably dozens of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use [.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
return "abcdefgh".replace(/[abc]/g, this.func_b.bind(this));
```

Or store reference to `this`,

```
func_c: function() {
   var _this = this;

   return "abcdefgh".replace(/[abc]/g, function (char) {
       return _this.func_b(char);
   });
}
```

[Example - 1](http://jsbin.com/viqeje/1/edit?js,output)
[Example - 2](http://jsbin.com/viqeje/2/edit?js,output)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ES7 binding operator:

```
return "abcdefgh".replace(/[abc]/g, ::this.func_b);
```

Note the double colon `::`. This is supported by Babel if given the right flags. See https://github.com/zenparsing/es-function-bind. See also http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman:bind_operator.

The main purpose of this enhancement is to stop the flow of identical questions here on SO from people who can't get their heads around `this` and wonder why `setTimeout(this.foo, 1000)` doesn't work.